# Adding an element to 2 parent elements

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to retreive data from XML and if variable1 == variable2, it will add the element (listboxitem) to 2 parent elements (listbox - listbox1, listbox2). I am trying to use the following code:

```
if (variable1 == variable2)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBoxItem);
    ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBoxItem);
}
else
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBoxItem);
}
```

I was thinking to get around this i may be able to duplicate the ListBoxItem but im not quite sure how.

Any help very much appreciated :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is build two ObservableCollections containing references to items from the xml data you've queried.

Instead of applying the logic above to ListBoxItem, apply it to each reference in the xml data and add the data to collection1 / collection2.

Then just bind collection1 / collection2 to listBox1.ItemsSource and listBox2.ItemsSource.

You have two listboxes referencing the same data then without the problems of duplicating ui controls within the tree.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have realised now that data binding is the way to go but i don't know where to start as I am only just learning C#. I have spent a while searching for tutorials on using binding with isolated storage but cannot find a good one, do you know of one? Thanks

Comment: The link in your other question shows binding data from a file in your xap. You can just as easily apply this approach to data you load from isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

Any control in wpf and silverlight can only appear only once in the object tree. So you cannot add one ListBoxItem to several ListBoxes. You can create a "copy" this way

```
ListBoxItem itemToClone = ...
ListBoxItem clonedItem = new ListBoxItem();
clonedItem.Content = itemToClone.Content;
```

So when `itemToClone.Content` is not itself a control but a string or a number you'll have two ListBoxItems showing the same content.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but I should have mentioned I am using a StackPanel inside the ListBoxItem so I am still receiving the "Element is already the child of another element" error.

Comment: @Jamie: Thats OK. So how this `ListBoxItem` was created in the first place? Cannot you create the second one the same way?

Comment: ListBoxItem lbi = new ListBoxItem();

stack.Children.Add(textblock);
lbi .Content = stack;

Comment: Well, then you can extract your `ListBoxItem` creation logic to the separate method and use it for duplicating them either. Or you can make use of [ContentTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx), which I think will be better approach, for it separates your data and presentation better.